# How we can create and debug a remote event receiver and attach it to existing list

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, remote-event-receiver

I have a custom list inside our SharePoint online and it contain many items.

Now I want to add some business logic to the list through implementing a remote event receiver which get fired when items are been created and edited. but I am not sure **how can I attach a remote event receiver to existing list**?

Last time I did so was around 3 years ago, where I followed the steps mentioned on this link and they worked well for me @ [Attaching Remote Event Receivers to Lists in the Host Web](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/26/attaching-remote-event-receivers-to-lists-in-the-host-web/).

But recently when i tried this appraoch, I got an error related to the fact that azure service bus (which will be used to debug the RER) has been retired and can not used any more to debug remote event receivers.

Now I found this link [Remote Event Receivers Creating and Debugging in SharePoint Online](https://blog.virtosoftware.com/remote-event-receivers-creating-and-debugging-sharepoint-online/), but it does not show how to attach the remote event receiver to existing list, as in this link they added a new list as part of the remote event receiver project.

So can anyone help me in finding a full documentation on "how we can create and debug a remote event receiver and attach it to existing list in sharepoint online?" and can I use a mix between the approaches mentioned on the above 2 links? attach RER to existing list and use Azure powershell to create the service bus?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for attaching an 'ItemAdded' event receiver with [CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM):

```
var serviceUrl = "https://remote-event-receiver-service-url";

var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList1");

var eventReceiverInfo = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation
{
    EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded,
    Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Asynchronous,
    ReceiverName = "MyTestEventReceiver",
    ReceiverUrl = serviceUrl,
    SequenceNumber = 10000
};

list.EventReceivers.Add(eventReceiverInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can debug your web service with the help of [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It forwards requests to a public endpoint to localhost.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. is there a full documentation about this?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the following post demonstrating adding/removing event receivers for lists: 
https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/01/add-delete-and-list-remote-event-receivers.html

But you're right - not so much info about this since MS recommends using web hooks instead: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks

Comment: web hooks will not work for me, as it does not support actions such as itemadding, itemupdating, etc..

Comment: That's right, but from my experience those synchronous events are not totally reliable. We encountered the situations when synchronous event receivers were not working for days. Finally, we reconsidered the architecture of our solution and migrated to web hooks.

Comment: now if we can not guarantee synchronous events inside SP online, then this is a another issue. as in the on-premises cases we were covering scenarios such as; let say we want to prevent certain users from modifying certain items, where we implemented these type of checking inside item editing server-side event receivers. now if in the online world those type of scenarios are not guaranteed to be executed, then our clients will put the whole SharePoint online into question...

Comment: ... as from a marketing point of view, sharepoint was intended to support scenarios where you can prevent add/edit items through using event receivers... we were not told that those scenarios can not be quranteeded to run on the online environments... so now is there a way to develop/debug remote event receivers inside SP online and attach them to existing lists?

Comment: In your case, I'd consider implementing a kind of permissions management system - provide users with permissions to corresponding items depending on certain conditions either in web hooks or recurring jobs/flows.

Comment: ok if the permission is the main concern then your point is valid, but sometimes i want to prevent updating an item if certain values do not match.. for example we have a financial sharepoint list, and as a rule when you create  an item >> you need to enter the original price, this price can not be modified alter on.. now i define a custom edit form >> hide the Price field.. but still i need an itemupdating RER, to check if the new value for the Price != old value,,then it should cancel the update request..

Comment: .. in the om-premises world i do these extra validation using itemupdating ER...those scenarios will not work with web hooks,,, also i heard that web hooks will expire after 6 months,, so we need to renew them...!! again i need remote event receivers...

Comment: @Dimitry Kozlov also here is a question i wrote earlier where i were not able to use ngrok to debug remote event reciever @ https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Unable-to-debug-my-remote-event-receiver-using-ngrok-Error-quot/m-p/401326